# Is there any difference between cudaMallocHost() and cudaHostAlloc() without special flags?

Tags: c++, memory-management, cuda

In CUDA, I'm wondering about the difference between [`cudaMallocHost()`](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/group__CUDART__MEMORY.html#group__CUDART__MEMORY_1gab84100ae1fa1b12eaca660207ef585b) and [`cudaHostAlloc()`](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/group__CUDART__MEMORY.html#group__CUDART__MEMORY_1gb65da58f444e7230d3322b6126bb4902).

Their respective summaries in the API reference say:

- **`cudaMallocHost()`**: "Allocates page-locked memory on the host."
- **`cudaHostAlloc()`**: "Allocates page-locked memory on the host."

And the further description seems to only be the additional flags one can specify for `cudaHostAlloc()`. Is the former kept simply for backwards-compatibility or is there an actual difference between them?

PS - Let's assume CUDA 6.5 and later.

Comment: @Drop: Descriptions seem to only differ w.r.t. the flags, and so do the signatures (although in cudaAllocHost the void** is refered to as a "device pointer" for some reason.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge they are the same when default flags are used for `cudaHostAlloc` and the call runs on a UVA platform. When the unified virtual address model was introduced, there was the necessity to expand the API to allow for portable memory and other new features, and it seems rather than fiddling with the existing function, a new "Swiss Army knife" style API was introduced instead.